# Javascript onClick not working in Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need a simple dialog box to let a user know they are leaving the site by clicking on a third party link. This works fine in jst about everything but Safari and Chrome. Am I doing something wrong? Here is an example of a link I am using:

```html
<a href="http://www.website.net" target="_blank" onClick="return confirm('You are leaving the example website!')">Sample Link</a>
```

Comment: Your code snippet works for me in chrome.

Comment: Does the browser console log any errors?

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome 40+, too. No errors, expected behavior. What chrome version are you trying?

Comment: For me works the same in IE as it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**HTML**

```
<body onbeforeunload="return confirmLeave(event);">
```

JS

```
function confirmLeave(e)
{
      return "You are leaving the example website!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have pop-ups disabled?
The snippets works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, using OS X 10.10.5
here you have a link for enabling them in [chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue in Safari. I think you need to add the `onclick` to an **actual element** like `<div>`, not on an `<a>` tag alone.

Replace this:

```
<a href="http://www.website.net" target="_blank" onClick="return confirm('You are leaving the example website!')">Sample Link</a>
```

with this:

```
<a href="http://www.website.net" target="_blank">
    <div onclick="return confirm('You are leaving the example website!')">Sample Link</div>
</a>
```